# Finding the arc length of a region defined implicitly with an interpolated function

Tags: regions, interpolation, implicit

I begin by defining an interpolation of some data I have [stored at this link for brevity](https://gist.github.com/jhwilson/10467024a973e3b8cf0acf4990a1a21d). The interpolating function is a function of two variables, `x` and `y`

```
S = (*data*)
f = Interpolation[S]
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -5, 4}, {y, -5, 4}]
```

[image]

I then want to define a one-dimensional surface by when this interpolated function intersects zero

```
R = ImplicitRegion[f[x, y] == 0.0]
RegionPlot[R, PlotRange -> {{-5, 4}, {-5, 4}}
```

[image]

This looks like it has worked quite well, but now when I try to calculate `ArcLength[R]`, I don't get an answer, even when I try restricting the domain of the implicit region

```
R = ImplicitRegion[f[x, y] == 0.0, {{x, -5, 4}, {y, -5, 4}}]
```

The ellipse looks pretty well-defined, is there a way of getting its arc Length?

Comment: Here's one way folks can import the data: `S = Import["https://gist.github.com/jhwilson/10467024a973e3b8cf0acf4990a1a21d", "Data"][[1, 2]] // ToExpression`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how accurately you want the arc length, but going along the lines you started, one can do this:

```
R = ImplicitRegion[f[x, y] == 0.0, {{x, -5, 4}, {y, -5, 4}}];
DiscretizeRegion[R, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01] // ArcLength

(*  19.7927  *)
```

A more accurate determination:

```
Module[{tf},
 NDSolveValue[{{x'[t], y'[t]} == 
    Cross@D[f[x[t], y[t]], {{x[t], y[t]}}],
   x[0] == (x /. FindRoot[f[x, 0], {x, 2}]), y[0] == 0,
   s'[t] == Sqrt[x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2], s[0] == 0,
   WhenEvent[y[t] == 0 && x[t] > 0, {tf = t; "StopIntegration"}]},
  s[tf], {t, 0, 10000}]
 ]

(*  19.7955  *)
```

It takes a bit of work to get there with `DiscretizeRegion`:

```
DiscretizeRegion[R, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001] // ArcLength

(*  19.7954  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a hack. Assume we have your plot: `pl` from the data:

```
R = ImplicitRegion[f[x, y] == 0.0, {x, y}]
pl = RegionPlot[R, PlotRange -> {{-5, 4}, {-5, 4}}]
```

We may no dissect `pl` to get the relevant information. Unfortunately, the line is not stored directly, but first the coordinates of the points are stored and then the line is specified by the indices of the coordinates. To get the coordinates of the line and to check if it is o.k. we write:

```
coor = g[[1, 1, 1]];
ind = g[[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1]];
line = coor[[ind]];
ListLinePlot[line]
```

[image]

Now the length of the line is easily calculated by taking the successive differences and the norm therefrom and finally adding up:

```
Total[Norm /@ Differences[line]]
(* 19.7268 *)
```

Comment: Slightly less hacky: `Total@Cases[Normal@pl, l_Line :> ArcLength[l], Infinity]`.

Comment: Michael E2 Hi, `Line` gives indices, not  coordinates. Reason: GraphicsComplex

Comment: Try my code.  I got `19.7268` when I ran it.

Comment: Hmmm, I get `306.008`. Look at `pl[[1, 1, 2]]` then you see that Line[..] is a list of indices. Only to make sure, `pl` is the output of Plot3D.

Comment: I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVDDU.png — Look at `Normal[pl][[1]]` and you'll see why my code works.

Comment: @Michael E2 Hi, it looks like `Normal`does the trick of changing indices to coordinates in `Line` . Is there any info to be found about this?

Comment: It's the last point under "Details and Options" of the doc page for `GraphicsComplex`.

Comment: @ Michael E2 Thank you, there is always something to learn.